# Keep check boxes checked in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have some checkboxes on a HAML doc, which should change the results displayed when I click the 'refresh' button. This works fine, but when the page reloads the boxes that were checked are all unchecked again.

How do I reconfigure the HAML to persist the checkboxes checked state across page views?

```
= form_tag movies_path, :method => :get do
  Include:
  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", '1', true
  = submit_tag 'Refresh'
```

I have also specified that the checkboxes should be checked by default, but they aren't checked when I load the page...

Comment: I think this could be quite complicated to achieve. You would have to save the state of the checkboxes between requests somehow. One way to do this would be to use AJAX to send a request every time a checkbox is checked. The server could then store the information in the session. 
Another way is to store the checkbox info in local storage, but this only works in modern browsers.

Comment: +1 @Jesper I think thats a good solution you have suggested, not too complicated. skeniver checkout [jquery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) send a request to a controller action on click of the checkbox and the store the ids (or whatever) of the checkboxes to select in the session and pass them into your view.

Comment: You can keep the checkbox logic out of the view, and that should make things way easier.  For instance, by setting a new class attribute to the params[:rating], then changing the values for that resulting hash from 1 to true, you don't need the complicated logic described in other solutions.

Answer (score 5):

This will accomplish what you want:

```
    = form_tag movies_path, :method => :get do
      Include:
      - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
        = rating
        = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", rating, if params[:ratings]; params[:ratings].include?(rating) end
    = submit_tag 'Refresh'
```

The `params[:ratings]` instance persists after the call, so you can just use it to mark the boxes that where clicked by the user before.

Answer (score 2):

supernova32 was very close.

The only thing missing was based on your last line "...specified that checkboxes should be checked by default."

Your code should look like this:

= check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", 1, if params[:ratings]; params[:ratings].include?(rating) else true end

Just include the ELSE statement for the times when the param does not exist (the default state.)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the checkboxes do not represent some persistent state of your business data (otherwise this wouldn't apply) but they are in fact a sort of "filters" or similar to temporarily configure the view.

In that case, you should request with AJAX only the results, and not the checkboxes. So you don't have to store them anywhere, as they don't go away.